# Codeblocks showing building error popup

Tags: c, codeblocks, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to compile a simple hello world program but codeblocks(v 13.12) is always showing me `It seems that this file has not been built yet.Do you want to build it now?`

I'd used codeblocks(v 13.12) before but never found this problem. I don't know how to solve it. Anybody please help me.

[image: build error message]

Image after creating a project: [image: after project]

Comment: Did you create a new C **project** through the IDE or did you create a C and header files load them into CodeBlocks and then attempt to build? You'd see this behavior if you didn't go through the process of creating a Codeblocks C project.

Comment: No. I don't know how to create a project!

Comment: You have to use File menu/New/Project  . Since it is a console app to print out hello world select "Console Application". Then select C or C++, and then fill in the information about the project. Once the project is created you can insert your own files and headers. The console application will create a default "main" function that you'll want to replace.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You are creating a project inside a folder that has a quote character in it! Many programs will have an issue with that. Try to create it in a different folder (one without a single quote character)

Comment: Look at what the error says: *Unterminated quoted string*, when calling the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd see this behavior if you didn't go through the process of creating a Codeblocks C project.

You have to use File menu/New/Project in CodeBlocks. Since it is a console app to print out hello world select "Console Application". Then select C or C++, and then fill in the information about the project. Once the project is created you can insert your own files and headers. The console application will create a default "main" function that you'll want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install it well: When in Ubuntu Software Center, before clicking Install button, be sure to tick GNU C++ compiles (g++). I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

This error is only due to **MinGW path is not properly** set. Remove any other compiler completely which uses MinGW.

To verify the path setting, go to codeblocks then
 - setting>Compiler>toolchain Executable 
 - Click on Auto detect, And try it, If not solve then do following 
 - verify that path will be set like this (C:\Program Files x86\CodeBlocks\MinGW) what ever the path you have But the MinGW will be in codeblocks folder.
 - If MinGW folder is not present with in codeblocks then you first need to insatal minGW and place it in codeblocks folder.

I also Faced this problem when I checked my path under toolchain there will be devC++ then MinGW compiler was installed Because I can't unistall it.

Answer (score 0):

You need GCC Compiler for C code compilinh and G++ compiler for C++ code compiling. Fire up ubuntu terminal and use the commands below to install both compilers.

sudo apt install gcc -for GCC compiler installation
sudo apt install g++ -for G++ compiler installtion.

Hope it helped.